# Compilar archivos typescript desde un script en package.json

Tags: typescript

Estoy realizando un proyecto en `typescript` y quiero ejecutar el comando que usualmente uso para compilar los archivos **`.ts`** desde un script en el archivo `package.json` y así podría ejecutar el script como:

```
npm run nombrescript
```

Este es el tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [ "es2015" ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "outDir": "src"
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*", "."
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

y así es como defino los scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ntsc",
    "build:watch": "ntsc --watch"
  }
```

**El problema que estoy teniendo**

Al ejecutar `ntsc` o  `ntsc --watch` desde la consola compila los archivos en el destino.

Al ejecutarlo como `npm run build` o `npm run build:watch` me salta el siguiente error:

> TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined

Si ahora cambio el script de la siguiente manera:

```
"build": "ntsc ."
```

Recibo el siguiente error:

> Error: references.d.ts not found in  . or any of its parents

¿Porqué no funciona el mismo comando si lo incluyo dentro de scripts en el package.json?

Mi objetivo final es poder ejecutar ese script en el postinstall. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar para ejecutarlo como `npm run build`?

Comment: Pregunta: ¿Por qué usas ntypescript y no typescript?

Comment: Pues no hay ninguna razón más que por quería probarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer el error era debido a que no tenía instalado `ntypescript` como dependencia.

Según la [**`documentación`**](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ntypescript#npm-scripts), esto soluciona el problema:

```
npm install ntypescript@latest --save --save-exact
```